# React Native - Second API Call is not returning value

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, fetch

My problem is that my code is returning an undefined value because of my second API Call:

```
render(){
    const result_postid = this.state.data_one.map(function(val) {
     return val.postid;
   }).join(',');

   const result_spaceid = this.state.data_one.map(function(vall) {
    return vall.spaceid;
  }).join(',');

   //These two will receive values.

    const result_image = this.state.data_two.map(function(valll) {
      return valll.image;
    }).join(',');

   //This last one somehow will not receive value
}
```

Here I am fetching two APIs in the same `componentDidMount`:

```
 componentDidMount(){
     //First API Call
     fetch(`http://www.exmaple.com/React/data.php`, {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {
       'Accept': 'application/json',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     },
   }).then((response) => response.json())
       .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          data_one: responseJson,
          },function() {
          });


   }).catch((error) => {
     console.error(error);
   });

   // Second API Call
   fetch(`http://www.example.com/React/image_data.php`, {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
     'Accept': 'application/json',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   },
 }).then((response) => response.json())
     .then((responseJson) => {

      this.setState({
        data_two: responseJson, 
        },function() {
        });

 }).catch((error) => {
   console.error(error);
 });

}
```

To confirm that it wasn't just a data response issue, I deleted the first to `const` (`result_postid`) and (`result_spaceid`) and the error was gone (`TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.state.data_two.map(function(valll){return valll.image}')`). The data showed successfully, but I need all 3 `const` to return the value. Is there a way to return all values for all 3 `const`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API calls are asynchronous, when you use the values in the render function some of them do not exist until all the calls return. You should have an initial state in the constructor

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.state = {
       data_one: [],
       data_two: []
   }
}
```

That way the values are not undefined. When the API returns the value, then the setState will trigger the render again.

Also, why do you have an empty function in the `setState` in the callbacks?

It should be something like

```
this.setState({
    data_two: responseJson, 
});
```

A couple of recommendations:

1. Use camelCase for variable naming, _ is not an usual standard in JS
2. Move the API calls to a different file, that will help you keep the component more organized. Then from `componentDidMount` you just call the function to make the request.

Comment: This worked, thank you so much! For that question, I really don't know why I have it, it was there from previous answered question and I picked it up. I'm fairly new to React Native. I'll also do more camelCasing and moving my API calls to different files. Again, Thank you! @CarolinaAguilar